# Locating the HDD in an Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have installed VMWARE Iplayer and Windows 7 is the host operating system (64 bit).

I have downloaded the ISO for Linux Ubuntu 32 bit and 64 bit Linux Ubuntu (there are two guest operating systems available in VMWARE i.e. 32 bit and 64 bit).  I am able to load the operating systems but there is no sign of my disk drives i.e. a SATA Solid State Disk and an IDE drive.

I have done some Googling, which suggests that they should appear in the DEV folder.  Are there any extra steps that are needed?

Comment: The virtualisation software will present is own virtual harddisk. Under normal/default configurations you should never see the real hardware (thus no SSD ir ancient IDE disk. Inside the vm you should see a /dev/hdaX or a /dev/sdX, depending on how the VM is configured. Could you add the virtual disk configuration to the post?

Comment: @Hennes, thanks.  There is no sdx folder or hdax folder in the dev folder.  How do I find the virtual disk config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is **shared folders** + **guests addon**.

> **Enable a Shared Folder for a Virtual Machine** You can enable folder sharing for a specific virtual machine. To set up a folder for sharing
>   between virtual machines, you must configure each virtual machine to
>   use the same directory on the host system or network share.
>
> Prerequisites ■ Verify that the virtual machines use a guest operating
>   system that supports shared folders. See Guest Operating Systems that
>   Support Shared Folders. ■ Verify that the latest version of VMware
>   Tools is installed in the guest operating system. ■ Verify that
>   permission settings on the host system allow access to files in the
>   shared folders. For example, if you are running Workstation as a user
>   named User, the virtual machine can read and write files in the shared
>   folder only if User has permission to read and write them. Procedure 1
>   Select the virtual machine and select VM > Settings. 2 On the Options
>   tab, select Shared Folders. 3 Select a folder sharing option. Option
>   Description Always enabled
>
> Keep folder sharing enabled, even when the virtual machine is shut
>   down, suspended, or powered off.
>
> Enabled until next power off or suspend
>
> Enable folder sharing temporarily, until you power off, suspend, or
>   shut down the virtual machine. If you restart the virtual machine,
>   shared folders remain enabled. This setting is available only when the
>   virtual machine is powered on.
>
> 4 (Optional) To map a drive to the Shared Folders directory, select
>   Map as a network drive in Windows guests. This directory contains all
>   of the shared folders that you enable. Workstation selects the drive
>   letter. 5 Click Add to add a shared folder. On Windows hosts, the Add
>   Shared Folder wizard starts. On Linux hosts, the Shared Folder
>   Properties dialog box opens. 6 Type the path on the host system to the
>   directory to share. If you specify a directory on a network share,
>   such as D:\share, Workstation always attempts to use that path. If the
>   directory is later connected to the host on a different drive letter,
>   Workstation cannot locate the shared folder. 7 Specify the name of the
>   shared folder as it should appear inside the virtual machine.
>   Characters that the guest operating system considers illegal in a
>   share name appear differently when viewed inside the guest. For
>   example, if you use an asterisk in a share name, you see %002A instead
>   of * in the share name on the guest. Illegal characters are converted
>   to their ASCII hexadecimal value. 8 Select shared folder attributes.
>   Option Description Enable this share
>
> Enable the shared folder. Deselect this option to disable a shared
>   folder without deleting it from the virtual machine configuration.
>
> Read-only
>
> Make the shared folder read-only. When this property is selected, the
>   virtual machine can view and copy files from the shared folder, but it
>   cannot add, change, or remove files. Access to files in the shared
>   folder is also governed by permission settings on the host computer.
>
> 9 Click Finish to add the shared folder. The shared folder appears in
>   the Folders list. The check box next to folder name indicates that the
>   folder is being shared. You can deselect this check box to disable
>   sharing for the folder. 10 Click OK to save your changes.

More details [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html)
(credits to http://pubs.vmware.com)